# Getting wrong value from Java ResultSet for some columns on doing rs.getString()

Tags: java, oracle12c

When I execute a query using `PreparedStatement.executeQuery()` from a Java application, I get a resultSet object with wrong values for one of the fields. When I use run the same query in SQL developer, then I see the values correctly.

For e.g. In my query output,I am able to see the values as below:

```
ID_TABLE        VALUE_ID
-------------------------
 1234 111111

 1234 222222

 5678 333333

 5678 444444
```

But, in java, when I am iterating the result set in while loop, I have printed logs with `rs.getString("ID_TABLE")` and `rs.getString("VALUE_ID")` on a single line as

```
System.out.println(" Table Id= "+rs.getString("ID_TABLE")+" -Value Id= "+rs.getString("VALUE_ID"));
```

Here, I am getting in logs as Table Id=5678 -Value Id=222222  which is incorrect. I am always getting the same output in sql developer and it is running in a single thread only. Nothing is running in parallel.

I am using Oracle 12c (version-12.1) and jdk 1.7.0_45.

Do you think it's a Java side problem or Oracle side data fetching problem?

Please let me know if you need additional details.

Please find below my method code snippet:

```
    Connection conn = null;
    ResultSet res = null;
    String strQuery = "SELECT ID_TABLE,VALUE_ID FROM AppTableDetails";
    PreparedStatement pStmt = null;
    conn = getConnection();
    pStmt = conn.prepareStatement(strQuery);
    res = pStmt.executeQuery();
    while (res.next()) 
    {
        System.out.println("Table Id= "+res.getString("ID_TABLE")+" -Value Id= "+res.getString("VALUE_ID"));
    }
```

One more thing, this error is occurring randomly and not every time when I run the process.

Comment: Please show the whole loop you use for fetching the data.

Comment: Please give us a [mcve] to reproduce this. Given the obvious typos (`getStirng` instead of `getString`) in your code, this is not your actual code.

Comment: Can you show your iteration logic too?

Comment: *"Please let me know if you need additional details."* - See the 3 comments above.

Comment: Can you also confirm that you don't have uncommitted changes to the values in your SQL Developer session?

Comment: @AlexPoole I have checked that there are not any uncommitted changes to the values.

Comment: The posted code looks ok. your error is something else.

Comment: @NathanHughes .. thats what I am wondering what could be the error.. but the code is exactly the same..